# Persistent disc on VM vs managed databases for Kubernetes cluster

Tags: database, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, google-kubernetes-engine

Migrating a Postgres database from Heroku to Google Cloud in a Kubernetes and Docker setup.

Trying to decide what is a better approach.

1st approach - Use a persistent disc on the VM that is used by a deployed Postgres instance in the Kubernetes cluster.

2nd approach - Use a managed Postgres SQL database that the cluster deployments connect to.

I assume the main differences would be for the maintenance and updating of the database? Are there any big trade-offs of one setup vs the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an opinion question so I'll answer with an option.

1. Kubernetes Postgres

   - **Pros:**

     - You can manage your own Postgres cluster.
     - No vendor lock-in.
     - Postgres is local to your cluster. (It may not be too much of a difference)
     - Do your own maintenance.
     - Raw cost is less.
   - **Cons:**

     - If you run into any Postgres cluster problems you are responsible to fix them.
     - You have to manage your own storage
     - No vendor lock-in but you still need to move the data if you decide to switch providers.
     - You have to do your own backups.
2. Managed postgres SQL database

   - **Pros:**

     - GCP does it all for you
     - Any problems will be handled by GCP
     - Maintenance also handled by GCP.
     - Storage handled by GCP.
     - Backups performed by GCP
   - **Cons:**

     - Vendor lock-in
     - Postgres not local to your cluster.
     - Will probably cost more.

Comment: This is excellent thank you Rico. I think it will take a little bit longer to setup connecting the cluster to the GCP managed database over a persistent disc but the ease of getting backups, scaling and maintenance done for you I think will be worth an extra cost.

Comment: The only query i have is the vendor lock-in. Do you mean you can't move the data to another provider or it's just harder? I can do a data dump on Heroku, and there will be some downtime which isn't great but I'm not locked into the provider. This would be the same case for GCP, it's possible just would be harder to migrate?

Comment: I mean it's harder, to the point that it would cost you so much money to move it out that you might say it's not worth it.